# Number of operations and cost of matrix multiplication

Tags: matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

Let's suppose we have a $2 \times 3$ matrix $A$ and a $3 \times 4$ matrix $B$.

If we multiply these two matrices, $A B$, we'll have $ 3$ multiplication and $2$ addition for each entry in the resultant $2\times 4$ matrix, which will make the total of $24$ multiplications and $16 $ additions , which will make it $40$ operations needed for matrix multiplication. Thus, the cost of matrix multiplication should be $40$ as there are $40$ operations done.

However, I notice that addition is not included wherever I read about it. Please explain to me where I am wrong.

Comment: Not all operations cost the same.

Answer (score 2):

Multiplying two $n$ digit numbers (by the conventional algorithm) requires $O(n^{2})$ basic operations on digits (multiplying two digits or adding two digits) while adding the two numbers requires $O(n)$ basic operations on digits.  Thus, for numbers with many digits, additions are essentially "free" in comparison with multiplications.

For a microprocessor with specialized hardware for floating-point multiplications and additions, it may be that the time to multiply two floating-point numbers is similar to the time to add the numbers.  In that case, a better way to analyze the computational complexity might be in terms of the total number of additions and multiplications.

The answer to your question is that computer scientists typically use the model described in the first paragraph of this answer.  Meanwhile, numerical analysts typically do their analysis based on the model described in the second paragraph above.

Answer (score 0):

The following algorithm uses just $22$ rather than $26$ elementary multiplications (at the expense of more additions and subtractions) to calculate the matrix product:

```
P01 := (a11 + a12 - a13) * (- b11);
P02 := (- a12 - a21) * (b11 + b22 + b31 + b32);
P03 := (- a11 - a21) * b12;
P04 := (a12 + a21 - a23) * (b21 + b22 + b31 + b32);
P05 := (- a13) * (- b11 - b31);
P06 := (- a12 + a13 - a21) * (- b11 - b31 - b32);
P07 := a23 * (- b22 - b32);
P08 := (- a21) * (b12 + b22);
P09 := (- a21 + a22 - a23) * (- b22);
P10 := a12 * (b11 - b21);
P11 := (a21 + a22 - a23) * (- b21);
P12 := (a11 + a12 - a13) * (- b13);
P13 := (- a12 - a21) * (b13 + b24 + b33 + b34);
P14 := (- a11 - a21) * b14;
P15 := (a12 + a21 - a23) * (b23 + b24 + b33 + b34);
P16 := (- a13) * (- b13 - b33);
P17 := (- a12 + a13 - a21) * (- b13 - b33 - b34);
P18 := a23 * (- b24 - b34);
P19 := (- a21) * (b14 + b24);
P20 := (- a21 + a22 - a23) * (- b24);
P21 := a12 * (b13 - b23);
P22 := (a21 + a22 - a23) * (- b23);

c11 := - P01                   + P05                         - P10;
c12 :=       - P02 - P03       - P05 - P06       + P08;
c13 := - P12                   + P16                         - P21;
c14 :=       - P13 - P14       - P16 - P17       + P19;
c21 :=       - P02       - P04             + P07             - P10 - P11;
c22 :=                                     - P07 - P08 - P09;
c23 :=       - P13       - P15             + P18             - P21 - P22;
c24 :=                                     - P18 - P19 - P20;
```